# Strange implicit memory management behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management

I have written the rotation procedure for a node in the red-black balanced binary tree drawing upon the Cormen's book pseudocode.

`N` is the tree node template class with previous node(`p`), left child (`left`) and right child(`right`) fields. `nil` is the special representation for the universal null pointer for the RB tree, the object of the `N` class.
When I added 3 nodes with sequentially increasing keys to my tree this procedure was called to balance the tree. I got the error in the 11th line, because the if case in line 9 was ignored and program tried to access `(x->p->left)` value while `x->p` had the NULL value. Using the debugger I found out that after the line 8 `x` starts to point on the `nil` value.

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename N>
void TreeMap<K, V, N>::leftRotate(N *&x) {
    N *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;

    if (y->left != nil)
        y->left->p = x;
    y->p = x->p; // line 8
    if ((x->p) == nil) // line 9
        root = y;
    else if (x == (x->p->left)) // line 11
        x->p->left = y;
    else
        x->p->right = y;
    y->left = x;
    x->p = y;
}
```

Then I had added the temporary pointer to the `x` and used it instead of `x` and the code executed as needed.

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename N>
void TreeMap<K, V, N>::leftRotate(N *&x) {
    N *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;

    if (y->left != nil)
        y->left->p = x;
    N *temp = x;
    y->p = x->p;
    if ((temp->p) == nil)
        root = y;
    else if (temp == (temp->p->left))
        temp->p->left = y;
    else
        temp->p->right = y;
    y->left = temp;
    temp->p = y;
}
```

Could you explain this behaviour, please. I have the assumption that this was due to the fact that after line 8 nothing holds the reference to the `x` except `x` itself and the memory was implicitly freed, but I don't understand why the simple pointer resolved the situation.

Comment: There's no language "C/C++". Code is C++, removed the C tag.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: And honestly, if you are using blatantly C++ only features, what possessed you to tag as C?

Comment: Are you sure that x->p is being properly initialised to nil when it is created, rather than being left uninitialised? Also, what is your reason for taking a reference to pointer to X as your argument? This seems...unusual...